# Pytest: How to discover filenames starting with a different prefix?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pytest, filenames, prefix

I am using VS Code + Python Test Explorer extension.

Currently, only the test files with a naming convention of `test_<somefilename>.py` are being automatically discovered.

Is there a setting I can change so that it can check files starting with a different prefix, say `moduletest_<somefilename>.py`?

I don't really want to change the file names of these files.

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer the question ? https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/example/pythoncollection.html#changing-naming-conventions

Answer (score 4):

Here's my solution:

1. create `pytest.ini` in root directory and tests are located in `root/tests`. In `pytest.ini`, add the following configurations:

   ```
    [pytest]
    testpaths= tests
    python_files = moduletest_*.py
   ```
2. in Settings.json, add

   ```
   "python.testing.pytestArgs": [
       "-c",
       "pytest.ini"
    ],
    "python.testing.unittestEnabled": false,
    "python.testing.pytestEnabled": true,
   ```

Then open test explorer, `moduletest_*.py` should be detected and shown there:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Since version 6.0 `pytest` supports [`pyproject.toml`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.2.x/reference/customize.html#pyproject-toml) setup. To make it work use

```
# pyproject.toml
[tool.pytest.ini_options]
minversion = "6.0"
addopts = "-ra -q"
testpaths = [
    "tests",
    "integration",
]
python_files = [
    "moduletest_*.py",
    "*_moduletest.py",
    "test_*.py",
    "*_test.py",
]
```

Please Note:

> One might wonder why `[tool.pytest.ini_options]` instead of `[tool.pytest]` as is the case with other tools.
>
> The reason is that the pytest team intends to fully utilize the rich TOML data format for configuration in the future, reserving the `[tool.pytest]` table for that. The ini_options table is being used, for now, as a bridge between the existing .ini configuration system and the future configuration format.

Answer (score 0):

You should set `moduletest_*.py` to [python_files](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/reference/reference.html#confval-python_files) in [pytest.ini](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.3.x/reference/customize.html#pytest-ini) as shown below. *By default, `test_*.py` and `*_test.py` are looked for if you don't set `python_files` in `pytest.ini` according to [the doc](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/reference/reference.html#confval-python_files):

```ini
# "pytest.ini"

[pytest]
python_files = moduletest_*.py # Here
```